# Replacing a string gives "A definition for the symbol "..." could not be located" error VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2019

I want to change a section of code that has thousands of lines. The section I want to change exists on many lines and I don't want to do it one by one. When I right click on FormQQ_ATL and say replace, it gives "A definition for the symbol FormQQ_ATL could not be located error VS2019".image:
[image] I guess I can't do that because it is a string. Is there way to solve this situation?

Comment: find/replace; replace all will do the job if it is sufficiently unique.  If you plan to change it again in the future, consider factoring them all to use a single const QString so you can change it in one place later.

Comment: Well, you are right. For my situation, I opened all the code via notepad++ and I changed necessary parts there.